# Tensorflow keras error AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'lower'

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

I have code:

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.text import Tokenizer
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.sequence import pad_sequences
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Embedding, LSTM, Dense

conversations = [
    ("Hello", "Hi there!"),
    ("How are you?", "I'm doing well, thanks."),
    ("What's your name?", "I'm a chatbot."),
]

tokenizer = Tokenizer()
tokenizer.fit_on_texts(conversations)

vocab_size = len(tokenizer.word_index) + 1

sequences = tokenizer.texts_to_sequences(conversations)
max_sequence_len = max([len(seq) for seq in sequences])

X, y = zip(*sequences)
X = pad_sequences(X, maxlen=max_sequence_len, padding='post')
y = pad_sequences(y, maxlen=max_sequence_len, padding='post')

model = Sequential([
    Embedding(vocab_size, 64, input_length=max_sequence_len, mask_zero=True),
    LSTM(100, return_sequences=True),
    Dense(vocab_size, activation='softmax')
])

model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])

model.fit(X, y, epochs=50, verbose=1)

def generate_response(input_text):
    input_seq = tokenizer.texts_to_sequences([input_text])
    padded_input = pad_sequences(input_seq, maxlen=max_sequence_len, padding='post')
    predicted_output = model.predict(padded_input)
    predicted_word_index = tf.argmax(predicted_output, axis=-1).numpy()
    response = tokenizer.sequences_to_texts(predicted_word_index)
    return response[0]

while True:
    user_input = input(">>> ")
    response = generate_response(user_input)
    print(f"Chatbot: {response}")
```

But I have error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\mceca\Desktop\chatbot.py", line 14, in <module>
    tokenizer.fit_on_texts(conversations)
  File "C:\Users\mceca\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\keras\preprocessing\text.py", line 293, in fit_on_texts
    seq = text_to_word_sequence(
  File "C:\Users\mceca\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\keras\preprocessing\text.py", line 74, in text_to_word_sequence
    input_text = input_text.lower()
AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'lower'
```

I have installed tensorflow==2.12.0

I don't want to change tensorflow version, and my OS is windows 10 and I don't have GPU, I only have CPU.

I work with keras, but if you have suggestion for other way in tensorflow, you can suggest me.

How I can fix this error? If you have more answers, type all.

Comment: Can you try making `conversations`` a list of _lists_ instead of tuples? See [the docs](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/preprocessing/text/Tokenizer#fit_on_texts), they only mentions lists of lists. I looked at the source code and it seems a bit brittle, lists of tuples won't be recognized properly.